# Migrating an asp.net 2.0 website to asp.net 4.5 version

Tags: asp.net, migration, asp.net-4.5

Hi my one of the project is developed on asp.net 2.0 and we got the requirement to migrate my project into asp.net 4.5 can anyone please help me what are the major changes and risk levels i can able to face by this migration and also suggest me what is best approach to follow the migration.

Comment: if it is a pure asp.net project from 2.0 to 4.5 the answer is any.

Comment: yes it is pure asp.net @Dalorzo

Comment: then there is nothing to worry about